# How to Upload my local Azure Function App Project to Azure Function Run time?

Tags: azure, azure-function-app-proxy

I have created an Azure Function App project using visual Studio 2017 for getting the API to my personal use, and I have already installed the Azure Function Runtime(Preview) setup.

[image]

My question is, how can I upload my local project to the Azure Functions Runtime.
So, anyone can please give a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your Functions to `Azure Functions Runtime(preview)` by clicking **Download publish profile** from the Azure Functions Runtime Portal and then **import** it in Visual Studio in the Publish.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I already did this process, but I receive an issue like 'Publish Failed'. Is it have any publish flow? Please tell me...

Comment: You could go to output to see what error you have got when publish and refer to this blog to [troubleshoot](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amol/2011/02/09/errors-seen-while-using-msbuild-to-deploy-on-a-remote-iis-server-and-their-solutions/). BTW, the iisApp provider has some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd569054(v=ws.10))

Comment: @JoeyCai I have the same problem. And all Visual Studio outputs are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the research and work I have done with Azure Function Runtime Preview, there is no way you can publish an existing Azure Function from Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise into on-prem Azure Function Runtime Preview - you can only create Azure Function in it.